# How to use scrollbar and fast Scroll to NestedScrollView

Tags: android, user-interface, scroll, nestedscrollview

I'm using NestedScrollView with Coordinator layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <...AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            app:contentScrim="@color/my_primary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <include
                layout="@layout/calendar_view"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </...AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to add a scroll bar to drag the scroll view using it (Fast Scroll). It looks like NestedScrollView doesn't have fastScroll attribute.

I tried adding

```
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
```

All of this didn't Work.